# What specific criteria does Google use to identify and measure great content when it comes to ranking?

Tags: seo, content

One of the primary advices I've been reading about SEO is to put out great content. But how exactly does Google measure that? What specific metrics does it use?

I understand how it identifies bad content (poor spelling, bad grammar, poorly structured article, keyword spamming, etc.).

But I have yet to find a clear criteria for how Google determines great content.

Comment: There are a lot of specific metrics mentioned in the post I linked.

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister for your response. I'm not sure that directly answers my question as those are more structural things in how a page is formatted. For example, I could follow all of those guidelines but the written content itself could be really poor. Would google still consider it "great content"?

Comment: Like two metrics that come to mind that might be used is bounce rate and time spent on a page. Is that correct?

Comment: Google's crawler isn't smart enough to read an article and grade it like a college professor, so it relies a lot on secondary signals. If your article is great, other high-quality websites will link to it, which google will see. If your article is great, people will share it on social media which google will see. Google does not rank using bounce rate and time spent on page [because they find it unreliable](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-does-not-use-pogo-sticking-as-a-ranking-factor/261629/).

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister That's actually very helpful and makes sense. One last question. Does it help a user lands on your page and checks out other pages on your website?

Comment: No, not directly. Google has no way of knowing what a user is doing on your website (unless you integrate Google Analytics, which I'm nearly 100% certain doesn't share any data with Google's search ranking engine). It could help indirectly though as the more of your content a user discovers, the more likely they are to share it on social media and create backlinks for you.